# Is it possible get a list of attributes from array and store them in a const variable?

Tags: javascript

I am curious if this problem has a solution. For instance, given array as follows:

```
const columns = [
    {
        accessor: 'id',
        name: 'ID'
    },
    {
        accessor: 'name',
        name: 'name'
    }
];
```

I only know to store attribute 'accessor' in this way:

```
let accessors = [];
columns.map((column, key) => {
    accessors.push(column.accessor);
});
```

But this means the resulting array 'accessors' is modifiable not a const.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can directly return values from map, then you can use the `const` statement.

```js
const columns = [
    {
        accessor: 'id',
        name: 'ID'
    },
    {
        accessor: 'name',
        name: 'name'
    }
];

const accessors = columns.map(column => column.accessor);
console.log(accessors);
```

Unfortunately just using const will not stop the array from being mutated, it will only stop `accessors` from being reassigned, or redeclared. However, you can freeze the array however to avoid mutations:

```js
const columns = [
    {
        accessor: 'id',
        name: 'ID'
    },
    {
        accessor: 'name',
        name: 'name'
    }
];

const accessors = columns.map((column, key) => column.accessor);
Object.freeze(accessors);
// EXPECT ERROR
accessors.push('test');
console.log(accessors);
```

Comment: (Noting that objects in the array can be modified unless also frozen.)

Answer (score 0):

The values `accessors` stores will be modifiable whether you make it a `let` or `const`. As stated in the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const):

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its parameters) can be altered.

So you can just change the line from

```
let accessors = [];
```

to

```
const accessors = [];
```

to prevent `accessors` from being reassigned, but you cannot prevent its contents from being changed using `const`.